# Using Request class to access Eloquent Models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

In my application, when the form is submitted, the $_POST items are stored here in my controller;

```
$input = Request::except('postcode_id'); //all the input from the form except postcode_id
```

A print_r of that will look like this;

```
Array
(
  [country] => Array
    (
        [0] => E92000001
        [1] => L93000001
    )

  [county] => Array
    (
        [0] => E10000003
        [1] => E10000006
    )
)
```

`country` and `county` have their own models, called Country and County respectively. How can I call this within a loop in my controller to access those models?

I was thinking something like;

```
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
            $ucfirst = ucfirst($key); //Try turning `country` in to `Country`
            $selection = $ucfirst::description($subvalue)->get()->first();
        }
    }
```

But that gave me an error of `Class 'Country' not found`

The `description` method in that loop is a [`Scope`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#query-scopes) by the way. Here is the from the Country model;

```
public function scopeDescription($query, $code)
{
    $query->where('code', '=', $code);
}
```

I just need a way of looping through what was selected on the form. Each field is a multi select dropdown. And each field is a table in the database.

Comment: If you're using using Laravel5, you controller is probably not in the same namespace as your models. So you have to either `use YourAppNamespace\Country;` at the top or prefix the `$ucfirst` with '\YourAppNamespace\'.

Comment: I have namespace `use App\Models\Country;` (and all the other models) listed at the top of the controller. I have no problem accessing the models manually like `Country::all()` for example

Comment: That's weird... Because it clearly says that it couldn't find the class. You could try running `composer dump-auto -o`, `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan optimize` to flush everything, at least for me this solves 90% of the problems when Laravel says it couldn't find a class even though it's there.

Comment: No that didn't work. Do you generally agree that using a variable to represent the Model name should work then?

Comment: Even though i personally absolutely do not like that, yes, that should work (here's quick proof of concept, without namespaces though: http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/Rip7iH). But I'd rather go with something like a switch-case flow control to handle that instead of gluing the class name together (especially for readability reasons). Anyway, the error message indicates that it actually *is* looking for the right class but can't find it, and I can't think of another explanation than wrong namespace or unflushed autoload-hashes right now...

Comment: Wait, actually... If you `use App\Models\Country;`, the error message should actually be `Class 'App\Models\Country' not found`. So it really looks like a namespace issue.

Comment: Ok, I did a little research, here's the issue: *"One must note that when using a dynamic class name, function name or constant name, the "current namespace", as in http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php is global namespace."* (http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php#112942) - so yeah, if you want to do it dynamically, you have to tack on the whole namespace, no matter the current namespace.

Comment: It's still not working for me. Even with the whole namespace used. Switch-case or something might be more practical. This is unworkable